# PHP MySQL query from date variable

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to query a table from my DB based on a date user input.
This is my code:

```
<input type="date" name="date" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>">
<input type="submit" value=">" onclick="showDate(this.value)">
```

for the user input (its defaulted to the current date)

and here is my php script

```
$q = $_GET['date'];

$sql="SELECT * FROM mathtest WHERE testdate = '$q'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

this is my ajax script:

```
<script>
function showDate(str) {
if (str == "") {
document.getElementById("mathtestHere").innerHTML = "";
return;
} else {
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("mathtestHere").innerHTML = 
this.responseText;
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET","getmathdate.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
}
</script>
```

and my php echo function:

```
echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>First name</th>
<th>Last name</th>
<th>Level</th>
<th>Time</th>
<th>Score</th>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Added by</th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['firstname'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['lastname'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['testlevel'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['testtime'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['testscore'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['testdate'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['addedBy'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($con);
```

and then echo'd into a php table. I'm using an AJAX onclick function to render the tables into my body.

For some reason, it won't show the tests that were taken on that date. 
Thanks!

Comment: What is the `datatype` of testdate column?

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: I know this isn't what the question relates to, but remember to escape your parameters

Comment: How do you echo the result? You also just added the submit button that's calling some JS. There are many unknowns here. You need to show us _all_ relevant code (from the input field => submit button => js function => query => echo of the result).

Comment: @MayankPandeyz the data type is set to "date" on mysql

Comment: @MagnusEriksson yes sir, i am still building up all the features to make sure they all work before strip slashing and escaping. thanks!

Comment: Please show Ajax code, and full PHP code (how you echo `$result`).

Comment: You shouldn't strip or escape the data. You should use prepared statements, which is much more secure. I also recommend you doing that from the start, instead of trying to fix bugs like this in code that you're going to change anyway.

Comment: Does the ajax request get executed correctly? Checked the console for errors / messages? Checked the network tab in the browsers developer tools to see what the actual response is? Checked if the query has any errors? Checked the servers error log?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson yes, everything seems to be working fine. I believe the issue here is the lack of quotation marks in the input variable being sent to query. is there a work around?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson when i run this query on myphpadmin SELECT * FROM `mathtest` WHERE `testdate` = "2017-05-16" it returns the correct results. I think that my php is seting the query without the quotation marks around the date input, thus giving the error

Comment: Uhm, isnt the this.value in this one: `<input type="submit" value=">" onclick="showDate(this.value)">` not > rather than the date the user gave?

Comment: @TroelsM.B.Jensen - It sure should be. Good catch.

Comment: @TroelsM.B.Jensen i see it now! now, i have 2 inputs - one that defaults the date to the current date and another input as a submit. how do i get the value from the date input to be submitted as the submit input value?

Comment: @shaunY I am working on an answer atm, it will be coming in a minute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of your rather crucial mistakes is

```
<input type="submit" value=">" onclick="showDate(this.value)">
```

Since the input is the `this`and the `.value` in this case is `>` instead of the date.

To get around this problem, I changed your HTML code to this:

```
<input type="date" name="date" id="date-selector" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>">
<input type="submit" value=">" onclick="showDate()">
```

and the javascript:

```
function showDate() {
    var str = document.getElementById("date-selector").value;
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("mathtestHere").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("mathtestHere").innerHTML =
                    this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getmathdate.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! It is very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If your data type of your `testdate` column in your db is `date` then the issue with date format. you should try you php like this.

```
$q = $_GET['date'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM mathtest WHERE testdate = STR_TO_DATE('$q','%Y-%m-%d')";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

First is the `onclick` attribute on your button with the value of `>`:

```
<input type="submit" value=">" onclick="showDate(this.value)">
```

What would happen here is it will pass the value of the button instead of the value of the date field. Just remove the `value` attribute of the button and the `this.value` parameter of your `showDate` function:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="showDate()">
```

And assign an `id` attribute for your date field:

```
<input type="date" name="date" id="date" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>">
```

Then on your script, we have to get the value of the date:

```
function showDate() {

    var str = document.getElementById("date").value; /* GET THE VALUE OF DATE FIELD */

    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("mathtestHere").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else {

    /** CONTINUATION OF YOUR SCRIPT HERE **/
```

#### Where is the div?

Just make sure that you have a `div` element that has an `id` attribute of `mathtestHere` :

```
<div id="mathtestHere"></div> <!-- RESULT WILL BE PUT HERE -->
```

---

#### Don't ever bind a raw variable to your query!

Lets go to your `getmathdate.php` file. Lets use [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) instead to secure the variable to be binded in your script:

```
/** INCLUDE HERE YOUR DATABASE CONNECTION **/

$q = !empty($_GET['q'])?$_GET['q']:'';

$a = '<table>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>First name</th>
            <th>Last name</th>
            <th>Level</th>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th>Score</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Added by</th>
        </tr>';

$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT id, firstname, lastname, testlevel, testtime, testscore, testdate, addedBy FROM mathtest WHERE testdate = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $q);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($id, $firstname, $lastname, $testlevel, $testtime, $testscore, $testdate, $addedby);
while($stmt->fetch()){
    $a .= '<tr>
               <td>'.$id.'</td>
               <td>'.$firstname.'</td>
               <td>'.$lastname.'</td>
               <td>'.$testlevel.'</td>
               <td>'.$testtime.'</td>
               <td>'.$testscore.'</td>
               <td>'.$testdate.'</td>
               <td>'.$addedby.'</td>
           </tr>';
}
$stmt->close();

$a .= '</table>';

echo (!empty($q))?$a:'No results found.';
```

Also check for errors on your console log. You can usually found this by hitting F12 on your browser.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I'm still learning the process so this is huge for me and I'll definitely stick to prepared statements in all my future projects